# Get InstallDir from regedit - CMD/Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

This is my batch code:

```
@echo off
title Program
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\Program
start xxxx.exe
exit
```

And my question is... how i can find this part: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\Program` with batch file if I do not know where the program was installed? I need to get install path from InstallDir in regedit. It is possible to do?

I need to do something like this:

```
@echo off
title Program
*here get program path from InstallDir in regedit*
start xxxx.exe
exit
```

-

Regedit path: `Software\Company\Program` - here i got **InstallDir REG_SZ** value with program path(**C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\Program**).

Comment: Providing the actual registry root, key, value name and data would help, they cannot be 'sensitive information'! To get the registry information you'd probably need to use `Reg Query` in a `For` loop.

Comment: Please provide the actual registry root, _probably `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`_, and key, _it isn't really `Software\Company\Program` is it?_

Comment: this is pretty unclear. From what I get, you would need to know the application name, then do a search in registry to match that app and then pull the path from there to execute. Correct?

Comment: I have put your question back to how it was. Please do not remove your question content and replace it with an answer, _(there is an answer facility for answers)_. Additionally it is not possible for your reported working script to work but mine with either of the `Start` commands replacing the `Echo` not to. If you can show me to be incorrect, I'll happily concede, but to take my answer and change the last line for your two is not proper behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, *after changing `Company\Program` on line 3*:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1 Tokens=2*" %%A In (
    'Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Company\Program"^
    /V "InstallDir" 2^>Nul'
) Do Set "EP=%%~B"

Echo %%EP%%=%EP%&Pause
```

Your path will be saved in the variable `%EP%`, I have `Echo`'d that in the last line for demonstration purposes. You would probably need to replace that line with:

```bat
Start "" /D "%EP%" "executable.ext"
```

Or

```bat
Start "" "%EP%\executable.ext"
```

**Edit**

If you try the uninstall registry key, it may prove better for you. As an example:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1 Tokens=2*" %%A In (
    'Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\U‌​ninstall\Company\Program"^
    /V "UninstallString" 2^>Nul'
) Do Start "" "%%~B"
```

Comment: Yes! I am however thinking that he is trying to determine the path by searching for it in the registry and finding the path. so perhaps something like `reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE /f ApplicationPath /s` and then loop through the variables to find a match for `Adobe.exe` in each path and set that path as the execution variable... might be wrong though. :) If he does want to set it manually, then might as well manually go through regedit and set each path, unless it is for a specific app only.

Comment: No, u have right. Thats what i want to do. Find path of application and run it .

Comment: @DamianSilent That is silly.. why not just do this. `for %%i in (xxxx.exe) do @echo. %%~$PATH:i`

Comment: I just need to do this with registry. @compo `@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1 Tokens=2*" %%A In (
    'Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Company\Program"^
    /V "InstallDir" 2^>Nul'
) Do Set "EP=%%~B"
Start "xxxx.exe" "%EP%"` This code opening folder which contains xxxx.exe what I am doing wrong?

Comment: "start "%EP%\xxxx.exe"" opens another cmd file with xxxx.exe in title.

Comment: @Gerhard, there's no guarantee that the location will be in `%PATH%`, _I just tried it with `firefox.exe` and it failed. (On my system `Program Files (x86)` is in `%PATH%` but not `Program Files`!)_. Even if it was there, as they're holding back the name of the company, getting the actual name of the program executable is even less likely_. Damian, I gave you the `Start` command in my answer, but I've now updated it.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I created this:

```
@echo off
:CheckOS
IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%" (GOTO 64BIT) ELSE (GOTO 32BIT)

:64BIT
FOR /F "Skip=2 tokens=2*" %%A IN (
   'REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\NFSMW" /v InstallDir'
) DO (set cdNFSMW=%%B)

GOTO END

:32BIT
FOR /F "Skip=2 tokens=2*" %%A IN (
   'REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\Electronic Arts\NFSMW" /v InstallDir'
) DO (set cdNFSMW=%%B)

GOTO END

:END

chdir /d %cdNFSMW%
start unins000.txt
exit
```

And it's working very well. However, I do not know which way is better and more accurate?

This:

```
@echo OFF

reg Query "HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0" | find /i "x86" > NUL && set OS=32BIT || set OS=64BIT

if %OS%==32BIT echo This is a 32bit operating system
if %OS%==64BIT echo This is a 64bit operating system
```

Or this:

```
:CheckOS
IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%" (GOTO 64BIT) ELSE (GOTO 32BIT)

:64BIT
echo 64-bit...
GOTO END

:32BIT
echo 32-bit...
GOTO END

:END
```

What do you think? Oh... and one more thing - what's the value **"skip=2"**?

Is it important? Was it well writed?

Comment: Both ways mentioned works about the same, it pretty much depends on how many lines you want to create in a batch. I would however say you should test both on a 64bit and 32bit machine as well as the different windows versions you have.

Comment: I checked on a 32 bit laptop and it works fine. On PC x64 - same.But I read somewhere that windows 2000 does not have the reg.exe module and may have problems running this script on that system. Is that true?

Comment: Yes. but it can be download.. the really BIG question here would be, why the hell are you still using Windows 2000 machines? :)

Comment: Because the game support Windows 2000. Let's find someone who will want to uninstall the game and will not be able to. After all, how can he/she know that the system does not have reg.exe? :D

Comment: There are other methods though other than reg.exe

Comment: doing a for loop using `dir /S`, searching for a specific executable, then get it's path.